# Stuck in Fastboot mode

Tags: android

My Huawei ascend G630-U10 is stuck in fast-boot mode and since my battery is dead i cant force restart it, every time it pops up it goes directly to fast-boot mode and it wont charge at all. I tried all the fast-boot commands on windows and Linux mint but nothing helped. Is there any other way to escape from this loop?